# Error Starting Tomcat from Netbeans - 127.0.0.1 is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I've seen this issue covered on StackOverflow as well as covered as a Netbeans bug and reportedly solved.  However, I'm having this error and none of the fixes I've found have solved it.  Tomcat launches perfectly from command line but when launched from Netbeans throws the above error.  I removed quotes from JAVA_OPTS to no avail.  I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 and Apache Tomcat 8.0.36.  How can I get Netbeans to launch my server?

Comment: Goto Tools -> Options and select No Proxy radio button. This works if you are not behind the Proxy settings

Comment: Thank you Shashanth, I'll try this when I get home.